# jquery cannot find dynamically created element in c#

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating an input box and trying to add an event keydown to that input. If I create the input staticly, I can find it with jquery. However, if I create it in code behind, I cannot find it by jquery.

here is the c# code where I create my input dynamically

```
result0 += "<div style='float:left;width:130px'>Telephone: </div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='txt_basic_telno" + i + "' class='blue_input' type='text' value='" + dr["MobilePhone"].ToString() + "' style='width:250px' maxlength='11' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div>";
```

and here is my jquery code which is supposed to trigger when user press a key during the focus is on the input box

```
$("#txt_basic_telno").keydown(function (event) {
        alert('test');
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: is your id 'txt_basic_telno" + i + "' or just 'txt_basic_telno' ?

Comment: would you please post it as an answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('keydown',"[id^=txt_basic_telno]", function (event) {
        alert('test');
});
```

Try not to attach this to `document` though as it's inefficent. replace document with the nearest static container.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGM7H) to demonstrate

**EDIT**

Stolen selector from dystroy.......his answers better but I wanted to keep the document comment as it's important

Comment: From the example I would guess that the id is dynamic (the `+ i +` in the code) so this won't work

Comment: @Andreas, yes, didn't notice this, think dystroy's beat me too it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('keydown',"#txt_basic_telno",function (event) {
        alert('test');
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: the first one's just plain wrong, your thinking of live which is depricated

Answer (score 1):

If your id isn't exactly `txt_basic_telno` but just starts with `txt_basic_telno`, as seems to indicate your code, then you might use this :

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', '[id^=txt_basic_telno]', function(e) {
     alert('click!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using two different ids : 'txt_basic_telno" + i + "' and just 'txt_basic_telno'

Answer (score -1):

jQuery binds the event handler to any existing objects that match the selector **when the jQuery function is called**, so if you want it to apply to the dynamically-created content you'll need to call the jQuery .keydown function each time after the new elements are created.

Comment: @Liam I'm pretty sure this holds true for those functions as well.  According to the jQuery documentation for .on() "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()" (http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Why the down-vote?

Comment: you sure? Because that's wrong! The event handler is bound to the element in the $ selector, which should be a static element, you then include a filter to the element you want to attach the event to, this does not need to exist when the on is bound. So your statement above is false, on, etc. were developed so you do not need to attach events every time you change dynamic content.

Comment: @Liam Yes, but it would also work with `click` instead of `on(click)`.  In your fiddle, the `<a>` tags are being dynamically created, but you're binding the event to the `<div>`.  If you were instead binding the event to the element that was being dynamically created, you would need to call the jQuery each time after the element was created to bind it to the new elements regardless of whether you were using `on(click…)` or just `click(…)`.  (I've updated your jsfiddle to show how just `click` can work.) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: But why would you do that? on was created for this purpose! if my parent element was being recreated I'd just attach to the document, http://jsfiddle.net/qYZB2/1/. It's cleaner and more efficient this way. If you re-binding your element everytime you change something and, for example, your using lots of dynamic elements your code will very quickly become unreadable

Comment: Wow!  I'd never even thought of binding directly to the document.  Thank you so much for the suggestion @Liam.  :)